# Is there any way to customize the URL of a HTTP request trigger?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

My logic app HTTP url is something like this:

https://prod-98.eastus.logic.azure.com/workflows/8767e7ecd19c45adbfb01d681e35a888/triggers/manual/paths/invoke/ABCDEFG/api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=U-M0hnvs9BICC_JV7_nTJRQhWg5oZnD_SVo9Sbm03oo

It is not presentable.

I like to make the URL of HTTP request trigger more polished and presentable.

Is there any way to customize the URL of a HTTP request trigger?

Using a clean custom DNS and URL path ( like https://MyDnsName.com/Path/Action ) is the prefrable solution, but anything better than what currenty provided would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, `When a HTTP request is received` trigger will automatically generate the URL, and it cannot be changed manually.

This URL includes query parameters that specify a Shared Access Signature (SAS) key, which is used for authentication.

I haven't thought of a way to completely customize the URL to `https://MyDnsName.com/Path/Action`, but there are two ways to make it look more meaningful.

**1.** Function App Proxy

After you [create an Azure Function App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function#create-a-function-app), you can [create an proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies#create).

[image]

[image]

After you create Azure Function App proxy, your URL is in this format:

```
https://<function-name>.azurewebsites.net/xxx
```

**2.** API management

After [creating an Azure API Management service instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/get-started-create-service-instance), you can [customize the URL suffix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-logic-app-as-api#-import-and-publish-a-back-end-api).

[image]

After you create a API management, your URL is in this form:

```
https://<API management-name>.azure-api.net/xxx
```